# Why every value is an object in python?

Tags: object-oriented, python-3.x

I know about writing programs (using C) that have:

1. Data values, that are manipulated. For example: integer, float values etc..
2. functions (rules), by which data values are manipulated.

object is a coherent abstraction of representing something that encompass it's properties(data values) + interactions (functions) && processes (functions) that can manipulate those data values.

As a python beginner, I would like to know, why data values (like integers and floats) and processes(like functions) are considered objects?

From Guido's [blog](http://python-history.blogspot.in/2009/02/first-class-everything.html) as mentioned below, I could find some relevant information but does not answer why?

> The internal implementation of Python made this simple to do. All of Python's objects were based on a common C data structure that was used everywhere in the interpreter. Variables, lists, functions, and everything else just used variations of this one data structure---it just didn't matter if the structure happened to represent a simple object such as an integer or something more complicated such as a class.

How can a computational process(function) be an object as per any language design?

Comment: What do you mean *"why"*?

Comment: Because Python was designed that way. If you are not happy with this don't use Python.

Comment: @WorldEngineer Is this query fit to re-open?

Comment: What is it about Guido's post you find unsatisfying? I think it answers the question; everything is an object in Python because it was easier to implement that way. I.e. There's no need for the Python interpreter to handle non-objects differently from objects.

Comment: @Doval implementation being easy to introduce everything as an object is not relevant reason for python programmers, what is the programming language principle that drive the decision to make every value an object?

Comment: @overexchange Python is whatever Guido wants it to be and there doesn't need to be a deeper reason than that. If you don't like that answer, go ask Guido! We can't give you anything better. We can't read his mind, and there's most likely no deep theoretical underpinning behind the decision.

Comment: @doval as per the definition of object mentioned in the query, can every value be an object? How can a computational process(function) be an object as designed in python?

Comment: Ahh, is that your bigger issue? You're wondering how the code itself is treated as an object?

Comment: You're probably a bit too new to programming concepts to get it, but here goes - when the python just-in-time compiler compiles python code, it creates what is called an Abstract Syntax Tree. This tree represents all the tokens and the program structure. Abstracting more, it stores small trees(one for each statement) as a code block, and blocks can be called like any method. Blocks can also contain blocks. So a method points to a function object, which is a subclass of block.

Comment: ASTL http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree

Answer (score 5):

If you have an object oriented language, then it should be normal and expected that every value is an object; you need special justification if that is *not* the case.

**Update:** it seems you're uncertain what the statement means, probably due to lack of contrast.

So let me provide contrast: in other languages, even those which are considered OO languages, some values are *not* objects. For example, Java has so-called "primitive types" like `int`, `char` and `double`. These are not objects, you cannot call methods on them and you cannot assign them to a variable of type `Object`. They need special treatmeant in many places, which is often a bit annoying.

The designers of Java chose to do this mainly for performance reasons, since objects typically have a certain overhead.

Comment: [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) says: `An object is an abstract data type with the addition of polymorphism and inheritance.` and `Object orientation uses encapsulation and information hiding.`  So, Does python object support all these features?

Comment: Uh. That's wrong. Objects and Abstract Data Types are fundamentally different. See [*On Understanding Data Abstraction, Revisited*](http://CS.UTexas.Edu/~wcook/Drafts/2009/essay.pdf) by [William R. Cook](http://WCook.BlogSpot.Com/). In particular, Abstract Data Types, as the name implies, achieve abstraction using static types, but Python is untyped (in the strict mathematical type theoretic sense) or more precisely dynamically typed, so it cannot possibly support ADTs. It does however support objects, which are an alternative means of data abstraction.

Comment: @overexchange in Python, *classes are also objects*.

Comment: @JörgWMittag For the point in section 4.1 `it says objects can be used to define data abstractions in a dynamically typed language.Objects do not depend upon a static type system;`, If you consider a object created in python `>>> x = 1 + 4j`. This object is an instance of type `class complex`(may be at runtime). So, type `class complex` is defining data abstraction and object *depend upon* type system in dynamic language as well. `class complex` is an ADT. How `class complex` is represented by python interpreter is an abstraction to python programmer. am I correct?

Comment: @overexchange `complex` is not an ADT; it's not even a type at all. A dynamically-typed language is a statically-typed language with only one type. An ADT creates a *new* type, which is why you can't have them in dynamically-typed languages. Like Jorg said, ADTs and objects are different things; in fact, they have dual properties. Every value of an ADT has the same implementation; objects can have different implementations. ADTs can have functions that inspect the implementation of multiple values (because they're the same); objects can't.

Comment: @overexchange If you're familiar with Java or C#, a `class` (with all fields `private`) is an ADT and an `interface` is an object.

Comment: @Doval a java `interface{}` is an object? May be, am new to OOP programming. Let me check all the points you mentioned in above 2 comments.

Comment: @overexchange in Java, it is possible to get an object that represents a class (an interface is a special type of class) and invoke methods on it such as `getDeclaredMethods()`.  See [java.lang.Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html). Note that this is part of reflection and going down that too far leads to madness and metaprogramming (really, don't try doing reflection until you have a good handle on what you are working with - unless you are very careful you start building very fragile code with it).

Comment: @Doval (and Jörg): Your responses here regarding objects/classes vs. ADTs are enlightening in a very ivory-tower-y type-system-theorist-y way, but are confusing for an OOP-newbie. A dynamically typed language is only unityped statically, but this is not a valid or useful observation during runtime. Of course `complex` is a (concrete) type, which is represented by a builtin class in Python. Classes are a kind of data abstraction, and they define a new type, which is all that matters for now. Interfaces aren't necessarily objects, and classes aren't automatically ADTs, but both are abstractions.